# Converting 2 column SQL query into string

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I need some help with converting a SQL SELECT (2 column) query into a string. Here is how the table looks:
(hID = autonumber, hName = string)

```
|@@@hID@@@|||@@@hName@@@|
|    1    ||| Yes hotel |
|    2    ||| Ok hotel  |
```

The SQLDataSource has the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT [hName], [hID] FROM [hotel]
```

So far I've managed to store in in an array. Here's what I got:

```
    DataView dv = (DataView)sqlHotels.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

    ArrayList hotelArr = new ArrayList();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dv.Table.Rows)
    {
        hotelArr.Add(dr);
    }
```

But my output should be a string that looks like this:

```
 var hID-1='Yes hotel';
 var hID-2='Ok hotel';
```

etc.

PS: I was looking at this:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-string-array-string
it makes sense mostly, but after my ammendments that would just give me something like `var hID-1;var hID-2;`. Not sure how to parse a 2 column array.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: can you give us the table definition?

Comment: “my output” to what? You're not outputting anything. What are you going to be using `hotelArr` for?

Comment: I'm using .net framework 4.5. @Dour High Arch, Well, I wanted to convert the hotelArr (array) to a string, but I guess it's redundant - thought it would be easier to comprehend for me to do DataView > array > string.

Comment: @Jester, What do you mean by a table definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the values out of the DataRow. Assuming that you have defined `id` and `name` variables previously:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dv.Table.Rows)
{
    name = dr[0];
    id = dr[1];
}
```

You can also index into the DataRow by name, like `name = dr["hName"]`. You should have a look at the documentation, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Tangentially, you probably do not want an ArrayList. If you specify what you're doing with this data we might be able to advise further as to the correct data structure.

Comment: `id = dr.Field<int>("hID");`  
`name = dr.Field<string>("hName");`  
`hotels += "var hID-" + id + "='" + name + "';";`

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to do it. Anyway, what I'm doing with this is creating javascript variables, as I am using bridge tables in  the database for my web app. I am using a repeater on the page to display information about rooms and instead of the name of the hotel, I've got the hotel ID - so I was looking for a way to change the hotel IDs into hotel names in the same asp.net repeater object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like :

```
var dv = sqlHotels.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty).ToList();

ArrayList hotelArr = new ArrayList();
foreach (Hotels dr in dv)
{
    hotelArr.Add(dr.hid.ToString() + " : " + dr.hName);
}
```